# Controller method doesnt return moq data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, model-view-controller, moq

I am trying to write Unit Test method for a Controller, but method that i mocked with test data doesnt return it.

My Controller:

```
IDataService _dataService = new DataService();

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult VerifyCredentialsAndGetUserData(string email, string password)
        {
            return Json(this._dataService.VerifyCustomerAndReturnHisID(email, password), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

My Library where method VerifyCustomerAndReturnHisID exists:

```
 public int VerifyCustomerAndReturnHisID(string email, string password)
        {
            var emailToCheck = new SqlParameter("@Email", email.ToLowerInvariant());
            var pass = new SqlParameter("@Password", password);

            var result = dbContext.Customer.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Email = @Email AND Password = @Password", new SqlParameter("@Email", email.ToLowerInvariant()), new SqlParameter("@Password", password)).ToList();
            if (result.Count() > 0)
            {
                return result.FirstOrDefault().ID;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

My Test Method:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void VerifyCredentialsAndGetUserData()
        {
            var user = new ApplicationDatabase.DB_Models.Customer()
            {
                Email = "basejohn@test.pl",
                Password = "testPass",
                ID = 12
            };
            var mock = new Mock<DbContext>();
            var userDbSet = new ApplicationDatabase.DB_Models.FakeDbSet<ApplicationDatabase.DB_Models.Customer>();
            userDbSet.Add(user);

            this._IdataServiceMock.Setup(x => x.VerifyCustomerAndReturnHisID(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(user.ID);
            var a = this._IdataServiceMock.Object.VerifyCustomerAndReturnHisID(user.Email, user.Password); // <-- this will return 12

            var result = this.loginPannel.VerifyCredentialsAndGetUserData(user.Email, user.Password) as JsonResult;  // <--- This never returns 12 
            Assert.IsNotNull(result.Data);
            Assert.AreEqual(12, result);
        }
```

I would like to have as a result data that i mocked which is 12, could somebody please help me, I am struggling with this for quite a long time...

Comment: what is loginPannel. This example seems to be missing some code?

Comment: Maybe `Assert.AreEqual(12, result.Data);`

Comment: Login Pannel is Controller from MVC project.
result.Data when i Invoke Controller method is different value (taken from normal execution from Database based on Entity call to DB) that i mocked for result so it wont do any good.

Basically in controller call is executed using 
```
IDataService _dataService = new DataService();
```